# TypeError : posts.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js

Server Error

TypeError: posts.map is not a function Unable to solve this error for 2 days finally decided to come see the gods here who can help me.Please!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import { PostCard, Categories, PostWidget } from '../components';
import { getPosts } from '../services';

export default function Home({ posts }) {
  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto mb-8 px-10">
      <Head>
        <title>ZenTech Blog</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/cms_blog/public/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-12 lg:grid-cols-12">
        <div className="col-span-1 lg:col-span-8">
          {posts.map((post) => <PostCard post={post} key={post.title}/>)}
        </div>
        <div className="col-span-1 lg:col-span-4">
          <div className="relative top-8 lg:sticky">
            <PostWidget />
            <Categories />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const posts = (await getPosts()) || []
  return {
    props: { posts },
  }
}
```

Here is the getPosts file,I am using graphqlcms and request to take post and details from here to the main index page:-

```
import { request, gql } from 'graphql-request'

const graphqlAPI = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHCMS_ENDPOINT

export const getPosts = async () => {
  const query = gql`
    query MyQuery {
      postsConnection {
        edges {
          node {
            author {
              id
              name
              photo {
                url
              }
              description
            }
            createdAt
            slug
            title
            excerpt
            featuredImage {
              url
            }
            categories {
              name
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `
  const result = await request(graphqlAPI, query)

  return result.postsConnection
}
```

Comment: Make sure that posts is not undefined before you use map
`{posts && posts.map((post) => <PostCard post={post} key={post.title}/>)}`
Could you share the code where you pass down the post props to home?

Comment: Is `getPosts` returning the expected output inside `getStaticProps`? Also, make sure you're using `Home` as a page component, `getStaticProps` only gets called inside page components.